# Conky-like app for windows xp

Tags: windows, windows-xp, software-rec, conky

I'm looking for a conky-like software for windows xp.
I don't need overblown widget/gadgets app - just a simple program to display hostname, IP address, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Rainmeter](http://rainmeter.net/RainCMS/) is the most popular program for stuff like this on Windows.

Comment: It seems it doesn't support fetching Hyper-V info. Do you know any other app supporting this?

Comment: I don't really use Windows anymore, but AlternativeTo is a good place to find such apps: https://alternativeto.net/software/rainmeter/?platform=windows